# Rails ActiveRecord: How to query the maximum value of column A and group by column B?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to do something like

```rb
  Model.select(column_a: :maximum, :column_b).group_by(:column_b)
```

I am using MySQL 5.6 and rails 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your DBMS max function and GROUP BY:

```
Model.select('MAX(column_a) AS max').group(:column_b)
```

Or using [`ActiveRecord::Calculations#maximum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-maximum) method, plus `group` as well:

```
Model.group(:column_b).maximum(:column_a)
```

Although the result is different as it returns a hash in the form as follows:

```
{ column_b => column_a, ... }
```

Comment: What worked out for me was `Model.select('MAX(column_a) AS column_a').group(:column_b)` as keeping it as max wouldn't show the value of the record as max isn't an attribute.

Comment: Cool @HHorns, you can add and accept your own answer.

Comment: I missed your second part of the answer. That hash is what I'm creating anyways from the data.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me.

```rb
Model.select('MAX(column_a) AS column_a', :column_b).group(:column_b)
```

If you keep the max value as `max` or some other name that isn't present as an attribute in the model, you won't see the value in the object as rails wouldn't map the result to anything.